# Instantiating a jQuery widget on content in a knockout foreach loop

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

If `.numberplate` is generated dynamically by knockout, how do I amend the below line to call it?

```
$('.numberplate').fitText(0.55, { maxFontSize: '60px' });
```

Edit:

```
<!--ko foreach: vehicle -->
    ...
    <span class="numberplate">N120AMK</span>
    ...
<!-- /ko -->

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.numberplate').fitText(0.55, { maxFontSize: '60px' });
</script>
```

Second Edit:

```
/*global jQuery */
/*!
* FitText.js 1.2
*
* Copyright 2011, Dave Rupert http://daverupert.com
* Released under the WTFPL license
* http://sam.zoy.org/wtfpl/
*
* Date: Thu May 05 14:23:00 2011 -0600
*/

(function( $ ){

  $.fn.fitText = function( kompressor, options ) {

    // Setup options
    var compressor = kompressor || 1,
        settings = $.extend({
          'minFontSize' : Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
          'maxFontSize' : Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
        }, options);

    return this.each(function(){

      // Store the object
      var $this = $(this);

      // Resizer() resizes items based on the object width divided by the compressor * 10
      var resizer = function () {
        $this.css('font-size', Math.max(Math.min($this.width() / (compressor*10), parseFloat(settings.maxFontSize)), parseFloat(settings.minFontSize)));
      };

      // Call once to set.
      resizer();

      // Call on resize. Opera debounces their resize by default.
      $(window).on('resize.fittext orientationchange.fittext', resizer);

    });

  };

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: you need to write the code after adding the DOM.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: First you add the code where you create the code, AFTER this you add the code where you want to use that element :)

Comment: What is this class based on? i.e. what is knockout using to determine which class to add?

Comment: Thanks guys, I've edited the question to show what I'm doing

Comment: By the way, I've tested this without the ko binding and it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use the afterRender option to call the jquery widget on dynamically created content. First, on your view:

```
<!--ko foreach: { data: vehicle, afterAdd: fitText } -->
    ...
    <span class="numberplate">N120AMK</span>
    ...
<!-- /ko -->
```

Then, on your viewModel:

```
fitText = function(element, index, data) {
    $(element).find('.numberplate').fitText(0.55, { maxFontSize: '60px' });
};
```

See the documentation here:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements

Comment: Yep - that's fixed it. Took me a while to figure out because my `foreach` was nested inside an `if` so it still didn't work. It does now though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the function "ready()" from jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.numberplate').fitText(0.55, { maxFontSize: '60px' });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: No joy :( Is it because fittext runs before the DOM is ready? See edited question

Answer (score -2):

The Knockout-way is just writing a custom-binding only implementing the init-function. 4-5 lines of code and you are clear in advance!

static example:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fitText = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).fitText(0.55, { maxFontSize: '60px' });
    }
}
```

html:

```
<span data-bind="fitText: {}"></span>
```